# OpenSSLfails on signature verification with “Unknown Option” error

Tags: openssl

I have three files:

1. test.json
2. public.pem
3. test.json.sign (Which is the signature of test.json with a private key)

I need to verify this signature. I use the following command

```
dgst -sha256 -sign pub.key -signature <signature filename> <data file>
```

When I try this command it gives me "unable to load key file" error.

What is the problem?

---

P.S: I googled the problem and I found a solution on this website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385320/verifying-a-file-signature-with-openssl-dgst)

It says I need to run the following command first

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

But when I run this command it gives me "unknown option" error!

Comment: This could be a character encoding issue. Look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/300870). Or just try it without the file output like this. `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem`